# Getting different local-port value in tcpdump when using --local-port option in curl

Tags: linux, curl, tcp, tcpdump

I'm using `curl` command to send the traffic to the Server. In `curl` command, I'm using `--local-port` option. Below is the command:

```
curl -v --interface 10.1.1.3 -b --local-port 10000 http://30.1.1.101/myfile.txt
```

I'm taking `tcpdump` to confirm that whether the `local-port` is used or not. Below is the `tcpdump` stats(image):

[image: tcpdump stats]

After checking the `tcpdump`, I have observed that the `local-port` value is different in `tcpdump`. It is supposed to be like `10.1.1.1:10000` not like `10.1.1.1:random_val`.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to force `curl` to use the same `local-port` that I have mentioned in the command?
2. What's the reason for getting different `local-port` value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If anyone knows then Please help me with this

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. The question is old, but can you provide the Linux and curl versions ? If using selinux, disable it and try again,

Comment: @EugèneAdell Sorry I can't provide the curl version since I left that company couple of years back and Now I can't access the servers anymore.

Comment: thanks and good luck with your new job